# Criar array associativo dinamico dentro de loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo dificuldades ao tentar criar um array associativo dinâmico dentro de um loop, o erro retornado no console é `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, a ideia é de um quiz esportivo com 3 perguntas para cada time, estou usando o atributo `"data-time"` que é igual nos 3 inputs deste time, dessa forma ao enviar o resultado seria criado um array com o nome do time sendo a chave e seus "arrays filhos" seriam as respostas.

Exemplo dos inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="respota1" value="respota1" data-time="flamengo">
<input type="radio" name="respota2" value="respota2" data-time="flamengo">
<input type="radio" name="respota3" value="respota3" data-time="flamengo">
```

Jquery:

```
var answers = $("input[data-time]:checked");
    var items = new Array();

    $.each( answers, function( key, value ) {

        var time = $(this).attr('data-time');

        switch(time) {

            case 'flamengo':
            items['flamengo'].push($(this).val());
            break;
        }

    });

    console.log(items);
```

Como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentado inserir algo que não existe na array:

```
items['flamengo'] não existe
```

Outra coisa é que neste caso onde podem ser marcados mais de um item, é mais adequado usar `checkbox` que é próprio para isso. O `radio` deve ser usado apenas quando se deve escolher uma das opções.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma nova chave desta forma a partir dos `checkbox` checados e ir dando `push`. Veja que nem é preciso o uso do `switch`:

```js
var answers = $("input[data-time]:checked");
var items = new Array();
var conta = -1;
var flag;

$.each( answers, function( key, value ) {

   var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
   var val  = value.value;

   if(flag != time){
      flag = time;
      var o = {};
      o[time] = [];
      conta++;
      items.push(o);
   }

   items[conta][time].push(val);

});

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="respota1" value="respota1" data-time="flamengo">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="respota2" value="respota2" data-time="flamengo">
<input type="checkbox" name="respota3" value="respota3" data-time="flamengo">

<input type="checkbox" checked name="respota1" value="respota1" data-time="vasco">
<input type="checkbox" name="respota2" value="respota2" data-time="vasco">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="respota3" value="respota3" data-time="vasco">
```

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso realmente são 3 names diferentes, a ideia é capturar os 3 values e inserir dentro do arrays items, sendo a chave o nome do tipo

Comment: Ah sim. Então é a mesma coisa que fiz na resposta. Ele vai pegar o que estiver checado e inserir na array.

Comment: Ele criou arrays numéricos e dentro desses o valor do time, o ideal seria assim:

[
  {
    "flamengo": {
"respota1",
"resposta2",
"resposta3"
  }
]

Comment: Quando eu adiciono outro time um um novo case, ele retorna: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: iguais aos que existem, só que o "data-time" seria outro, por exemplo, data-time="vasco"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78404/discussion-between-nba-youngcode-and-dvd).

Comment: Resposta atualizada.